# Slow boot time with Zenbook UX32VD (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8, drivers, ssd, zenbook

When I boot pc up, it takes long time to get to login screen (2:00-2:30 min). First of all, i seek help in [Windows 8 official forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itproperf/thread/187a764b-1d01-4883-b388-987a3fb5ba46). In my case it's probably caused by cache SSD and I have installed latest drivers.

I would like to ask, if anyone had the similiar problem or how to resolve it..

Comment: I already told you at technet which issue you have. Contact ASUS for support.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes I did, but also i try to find someone else with similiar problems.